# Efficient writing and saving of real-time data in Python?

Tags: python

I have a script that I am using to pull data from an accelerometer.  I am able to specify the bandwidth of the accelerometer (250 Hz), which sets the data rate to 500 Hz for sampling.

**The problem** that I am facing is that the `.txt` file is not saving the number of samples that I am expecting, and I am asking for support here to understand if my lines of code to write the data to the text file are the reason for my bottleneck.

Once this file is saved in the data collection scipt, I am opening the `.txt` file in a Spyder script, that is creating a real-time calculation and visualization of the data, as it is being saved by the first script.

The following lines are used in the 'data_pull' script, which is reading the data from the accelerometer.  The lines below are what I'm using to write to the text file.

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\test.txt","a")
writer = csv.writer(file)
while True:
      writer.writerow(convert2g(readField()))    
      file.flush()
```

For Reference, two of the functions in the data pulling script from the accelerometer are shown below.  I didn't include the entire script, because it is unrelated to the saving and writing to the text file.

```
def convert2g(raw_accs):
    return [acc / CONVERT_CONST for acc in raw_accs]

def readField():
    values = myBoard.Read(0x02, 18) #check register map

    bin_mask = 0b11110000
    acc_x_lsb = values[0] & bin_mask
    acc_x_msb = values[1] << 8
    acc_x = (acc_x_msb | acc_x_lsb)
    twos_x = twos_comp(acc_x) >> 4

    acc_y_lsb = values[2] & bin_mask
    acc_y_msb = values[3] << 8
    acc_y = (acc_y_msb | acc_y_lsb)
    twos_y = twos_comp(acc_y) >> 4

    acc_z_lsb = values[4] & bin_mask
    acc_z_msb = values[5] << 8
    acc_z = (acc_z_msb | acc_z_lsb)
    twos_z = twos_comp(acc_z) >> 4

    return twos_x, twos_y, twos_z
```

The code below is what I'm using to build the animation.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import numpy as np
import easygui
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate(i):

    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\test.txt")
    data.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    xar = range(len(data))

    yar = pd.DataFrame(data['Z'])
    yar = yar[1050:]
    xar = xar[1050:]

    std = yar.rolling(window=10000).std()
    std = std.as_matrix()

    yar = data.as_matrix()
    yar = yar[1050:len(data)]

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.set_xlabel("Sample Number")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Standard Deviation (g)")

    ax3.clear()
    ax3.set_xlabel("Sample Number")
    ax3.set_ylabel("Acceleration (g)")
    ax1.plot(xar, std)
    ax3.plot(xar, yar)
    ax1.set_title('Rolling Standard Deviation')
    ax3.set_title('Original Data')

fig, (ax1, ax3) = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.5)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `the number of samples that I am expecting` What are you expecting? Please consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your desired output is missing!

Comment: Another thing, if you are trying to visualize data in real-time i would suggest using tools like `elasticsearch` with `kibana` You can basically send the data and read it in realtime

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  To answer the first comment, I know that I am not receiving the correct number of samples, because when I sample with the manufacturer's development kit (with the same sampling parameters), I get 100k samples.  When I sample with the Python code (to allow for real-time visualization), I am getting around 25-35k samples.

Comment: I saw this question yesterday but had no time to comment.  It seems that your problem has several moving parts: capturing the data, parsing it, writing it to a file, reading and presenting that file in another application.  You have to isolate where the performance bottleneck is.  For example, remove all the parsing code from the function readField and instead just increment an integer variable; print that variable's value every second.  That tells you how fast you are capturing the raw data.  Go down the chain and repeat that sort of thing until you find where the problem is.